# Check how much time left to execute timer

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 11.

Let's say you put a TTimer on your form and set interval to 60000. It will execute one minute from now.

But is there a way to check how much time is left to the Timer execute ? For instance, after 20 seconds passed, the Timer will run in 40 seconds. Is there any method i can check to get this value ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is no. Don't use a timer for this.

Comment: Google "XY problem"